# Android send data from IntentService to Activity

Tags: android

i have a service which fetches some data from network.i am sending data download finish type of messages through messenger object like this

```
messangerClient.send(Message.obtain(null, MyActivity.DOWNLOAD_SUCESS));
```

and getting it in my activity successfully.But now i need to send data from my service to my activity.I cannot use Parcel framework because it is supported from 2.2.So i am thinking to send it via setData() using bundle.But i am unable to figure out how to do this.

Please anybody have any idea to how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are binding to the service, in the service connection callback, you will receive the IBinder object, use that and fetch your service object and you can call methods on it like a normal object methods

look at the way LocalService object is captured in the [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) mentioned in android documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the activity from your service then you can pass data thru Intent.

Comment: No i am starting my service from activity and binding it as well.

Comment: then you can make a static function in the activity and call it from your service with appropriate values.